# Retrieve information for a specific Object in a to-many relationship Coredata

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data, nspredicate

anyone can help me to find a solution in this problem, i have this Core data model:

[image]

EDIT:
i formulate better my question, i want retrieve all taskes for a specifc name of the entity MyDate that have taskes.isView = NO and task date = today..

Comment: What kind of property is isView? BOOL? NSNumber?

Comment: Do you want Tasks that have isView==NO and a taskDate with a specific name, or do you want Tasks that a taskDate with a given name and (*any* Task of that MyDate has isView==NO)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would fetch on the `Task` entity with the predicate

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"taskDate.name == %@ && isView == NO", taskName]
```

to find `Tasks` whose taskDate has name `taskName` and `isView` is `NO`.

If, instead you need to find `Tasks` that hava a `taskDate` with the given name and *any* of the `taskDate`'s `taskes` [sic] have `isView==NO`, then you need (fetching on `MyDate` entity):

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"name == %@ && ANY taskes.isView == NO"]
```

From the result `resultSet` of the fetch, you can get all of the `Tasks` using Key-Value Coding [Collection Operators](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002176-BAJEAIEE):

```
[resultSet valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfSets.taskes"];
```

Comment: Thank you very much Barry! you are the boss of the core date! :D

Comment: Nope, I've just been through it before. Glad to help.